# Domain server with name could not be contacted. Either the server is down or domain name is incorrect. The LDAP server is unavailable

Tags: authentication, server, dns, ldap

I am stuck with an issue. I am trying to connect to Ax2009 using wsdl url in postman. When i tried to access that url in browser i am able to access that but through postman i am getting LDAP error.
Error: Test connection failed. Reason: Domain server with name:ABC could not be contacted. Either the server is down or domain name is incorrect. The LDAP server is unavailable.

Code:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,AuthInfo.Domain))
```

Getting error on this first line.
Please suggest some solution for this issue.
Thanxs in advance.